# Function returns a collection with info from Access, but the calling sub cannot read elements of the collection

Tags: function, ms-access, collections, vba

I am seeing a strange situation when a function takes a column of field values from an Access table and put those in a VBA collection and returns the collection.  The function takes a table name and field name as arguments and returns a collection with all (or unique) values in the column of fields.  When a sub runs this function, the sub can read out a count of elements in the resulting collection.  However, when the sub tries to access the elements errors results.

I say “errors” because I get a different error when I try to access elements in different ways.  For example if I try to access a collection element via the key:

```
For i=0 to col.count
    Debug.Print col(Cstr(i))        ' results in error: "Automation error"
    i=i+1
Next
```

I get an “Automation Error.” But when I try to access collection elements via For Each

```
For Each var in col 
    Debug.Print var     ' results in  error: "Object invalid or no longer set."
Next
```

What is also strange is that the elements of the collection can be accessed within the function that will be returning it, but not once the collection is returned to the calling sub.  But the calling sub can access the collection count.

The same approach with Access tables works fine to put a column of field values into an array.  After the function returns an array of a column of field values, the array can be converted to a collection.  The resulting collection can be passed to and used in another sub.  But the method does not work to have a function get info from Access, pack it into a collection and return the collection with info from Access to the calling sub.

My code is below.  I've tried but could not find any even remotely related questions.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub colUniqueTableValues_tester()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim strTable As String: strTable = "tbl_Projects"
    Dim strField As String: strField = "Project_Code"

    Set col = colUniqueTableValues(strTable, strField)
    Debug.Print "colListOfUniqueValues_tester: col.count = " + CStr(col.Count)
    ' Set col = colAnyLengthAndStep(4, 1)  ' sub will complete if the collection from Access is overwritten

    i = 0
    For Each var In col
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print CStr(i) + ": " + col(CStr(i)) ' results in error: "Automation error"
        Debug.Print var ' returns error: "Object invalid or no longer set."
    Next
    Set col = Nothing
End Sub


Function colUniqueTableValues(ByVal strTable As String, ByVal strField As String) As Collection

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim col As New Collection

    strSQL = "Select distinct " + strField + " from " + strTable
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    i = 0
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        col.Add rs.Fields(strField), CStr(i)
        Debug.Print "Function: " + col(CStr(i)) 'check value
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Set colUniqueTableValues = col
    Debug.Print "colUniqueTableValues:  colUniqueTableValues.count = " + CStr(colUniqueTableValues.Count)

    Set dbs = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set col = Nothing

End Function


Function colAnyLengthAndStep(ByVal intLength As Integer, ByVal intStep As Integer) As Collection
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim var As Variant

    For i = 1 To intLength * intStep Step intStep
        col.Add "Value" + CStr(i), CStr(i)
    Next

    Set colAnyLengthAndStep = col
    Set col = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is due to the fact that `rs.Fields(strField)` is a field object.  In many situations, when you do something with a field, you're implicitly referencing its default property, which is `.Value`.  For example, these two are essentially the same:

```vb
Debug.Print rs.Fields(strField)
Debug.Print rs.Fields(strField).Value
```

However, the collection's `.Add` method is different in that it will accept the actual object itself instead of the object's `.Value`.  To see what's actually happening, make this change in `colUniqueTableValues()`:

```vb
col.Add rs.Fields(strField), CStr(i)
Debug.Print TypeName(col(CStr(i))) ' <- this says Field2 on my system
```

You must explicitly reference the field's `.Value` property to add it to the collection properly:

```vb
col.Add rs.Fields(strField).Value, CStr(i)
```

After that change, you will expose an error in `colUniqueTableValues_tester`.  When you added items to the collection, you gave them keys using `CStr(i)` starting with `i = 0`.  However, in the `For Each` loop in `colUniqueTableValues_tester, i` starts at 1.  Change the loop to this:

```vb
For Each var In col
    'i = i + 1
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & ": " & col(CStr(i))
    Debug.Print var
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, HansUp.  Mystery solved!  Now col.Add rs.Fields(strField).Value, CStr(i):   Debug.Print TypeName(col(CStr(i))) says "String".

Comment: It amazes me how enduring some answers are. Thank you, @HansUp.